# How to pass only integer value in key value in nifi

Tags: json, apache-nifi, jolt

I have a use case, where i wants to pass only the integer value in the key **datasum**, my input data is randomly generates with both the integer and string, whenever the **datasum** contain the string as below it should replace with 0

input JSON

```json
[
  {
    "hostname": "ip-192-168-1-1.demo-sample.com",
    "detail": "Host name",
    "datasum": "ip-192-168-1-1.demo-sample.com",
    "toolname": "nifi",
    "datacount": "1"
  },
  {
    "hostname": "demo-env",
    "detail": "System information",
    "datasum": "Windows DEMO-ENV 10.0.19 Microsoft Windows Server 2016",
    "toolname": "nifi",
    "datacount": "1"
  }
]
```

in above two records **datasum** having the string value and we need to replace it by **`0`**

expected output

```json
[
  {
    "hostname": "ip-192-168-1-1.demo-sample.com",
    "parametername": "Host name",
    "datasum": 0,
    "toolname": "nifi",
    "datacount": "1",
    "severity": "1",
    "createdby": "ApacheNifi"
  },
  {
    "hostname": "demo-env",
    "parametername": "System information",
    "datasum": 0,
    "toolname": "nifi",
    "datacount": "1",
    "severity": "1",
    "createdby": "ApacheNifi"
  }
]
```

please suggest.

Answer (score 1):

You can use toInteger function within a modify transformation spec along with a second argument equals to zero such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "datasum": ["=toInteger", 0]
      }
    }
  }
]
```

In this case, the function would silently stop whenever the value of ***datasum*** is string, eg not convertible to *integer*

the ***demo*** on the site http://jolt-demo.appspot.com/ is

[image]